# Change file names

Tags: file, matlab, filenames

I have a question about how can I change some files names. The problem is I have this kind of archives, for example:

```
25614_z.zip
25312_z.zip
25003_z.zip
```

And I want to create that:

```
lp_25_614.zip
lp_25_312.zip
lp_25_003.zip
```

So, I need to automatize this process

lp + 25 (the two first digits) + the number in the 3 4 and 5 position) + dot zip

Is there any way to do it?

**EDIT**

For example, this would be my condition:

**XXXX**

```
if fileNames{k}(3:5) >0 <5 (the interval)= 2
fileNames{k}(3:5)> >5 >10 =10
```

So, for example:

fileNames{k}(3:5) = 05

after the condition it would be replaced in the rename with= 2

And then I want to add it on the rename name.

```
newFileName = ['fiche' fileNames{k} (3) 'pd' fileNames{k}(3:5) 'XXX '.tar.gz'];
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`movefile`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html) to rename the files:

```
 myPath = 'C:\myFolder\'; % path to your files

fileNames = {
    '25614_z.zip'
    '25312_z.zip'
    '25003_z.zip'
    }


for k = 1:length(fileNames)
    newFileName = ['lp_' fileNames{k}(1:2) '_' fileNames{k}(3:5) '.zip'];
    % renaming
    movefile([myPath fileNames{k}], [myPath newFileName]); 
end
```

**~edit~**
Concerning your edit: yes it is possible to generate the file name different for separate cases. Note that the example below is quite clumsy and should only be used if you have only a small number of different cases.

```
myPath = 'C:\myFolder\'; % path to your files

fileNames = {
    '25614_z.zip'
    '25312_z.zip'
    '25003_z.zip'
    }


for k = 1:length(fileNames)
    n = num2str(fileNames{k}(3:5));
    if n > 0 && n < 5
        fileName = % put your file name for this case here
    elseif n >= 5 && n < 10
        fileName = % put your file name for this case here
    elseif n >= 10 && n < 20
        fileName = % put your file name for this case here
    end
    % renaming
    movefile([myPath fileNames{k}], [myPath newFileName]);
end
```

Comment: One question! I've got the name changed in a new array called 'NewFileName' but I don't know if it's possible to copy the same file as the original with this new name? Is it possible? thanks in advance,

Comment: To rename the file you use the command `movefile` like in my code example.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't create or rename that file from the original folder, isn't it? I don't know if I'm explaining well... (thanks!)

Comment: @user1578688 You need to either perpend the path to the file to both `newfilename` and `filenames`, or you need to be in the directory where the files are located (use `chdir`)

Comment: If the original folder is different from the folder you run the matlab script in, you need to include the path in the `movefile` command. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much H.Muster and angainor! ;) It works!! (I had some problem with the syntaxis!).

Comment: One question. It works perfectly but if I want not to overwrite the files and save the results in another folder, is that possible? I've checked the Matlab documentation and say that I've to use this kind of structure [movefile('myfunction.m','../projects')] but I received the following error: "??? Error using ==> movefile
No matching files were found."

Comment: Then you have to use `copyfile` and give a different path in the second brackets in `copyfile([myPath fileNames{k}], [myNewPath newFileName]); `. Note that you have to create the new folder before you can copy your files into it.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to add a condition to the code? I mean: 

fileNames{k} (3:5)>0-5 = 2
fileNames{k} (3:5)>5-10 = 10

Comment: I do not understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Hi H.Muster! I'm sorry, I couldn't check it before! I've tried with your code and I received the following error: "??? Operands to
the || and &&
operators must
be convertible
to logical
scalar values.
 " I'm going to check if I can solve it! ;) Thanks again!

Comment: I've solved the problem with only using &! ;) But if I want to write the result how can I do it? (fileName = 31) I mean this number 31 to the "newFileName"?

Answer (score 0):

As a more general solution you can use `regexp` with `Token` parameter to match parts of a string:

```
for k = 1:length(fileNames)
    splitname = regexp(fileNames{k}, '(\d\d)(\d\d\d)', 'Tokens');
    fname_new = ['lp_' splitname{1}{1} '_' splitname{1}{2} '.zip'];
    movefile(fileNames{k}, fname_new);
end
```

Here, the pattern in `regexp` is matches two digits followed by three digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot angainor! The last solution it works but i'm going to try yours too! ;)

Comment: It happens the same with your code! I've got the list of the new names but I don't know how to create a new 'file' renamed in a new folder. I'm trying to find how to do it!