# MatLab - dicm2nii - Custom output filenames (.json, .gz)

Tags: matlab

converting dicm to nii works great with the help of this script from xiangruili :
https://github.com/xiangruili/dicm2nii/blob/master/dicm2nii.m

BUT I need to modify the output filenames and add a string to it. The function save_json of the script (dicm2nii.m) was promising, but I am new to matlab and have the feeling that there is a simple solution to this problem.

Cant somebody help me, please!

Thanks!

Comment: You've provided a link to an external m-file which is 3,000 lines long and asked someone to suggest how you might achieve something fairly vague. Please read [ask], have a go at solving the problem yourself (i.e. can you edit the `save_json` function you identified to do something different?) and highlight where the specific roadblock is to achieving the behaviour you want. Currently your whole question could be distilled to `I found this code: _link_, and I want to add a string to a file name`, which isn't really answerable

Comment: Thank you. Next time I will try to narrow it down to a simple problem instead of a needless complex.

Answer (score 0):

As @Wolfie correctly mentioned, this is not something easily addressed for people unfamiliar with the particular program.  But I took a very quick look since I currently use other tools for DICOM to NiFTI conversion and was curious about this one.  Here are some general comments that hopefully will help.

- The "json" file is just for metadata, and you probably care more about the .nii image file (or both).  It looks like `nii_tool('save', nii, filename, force_3D)`  handles the latter.
- The nii_tool and save_json calls are just passed a variable containing the output filename, which you could create/modify using any of the standard MATLAB methods (e.g., `sprintf` or `strcat`).  There are already some examples of this within the code in the calls to `nii_tool('save', ...)`.
- Since you say that you are new to MATLAB, it is probably easiest for you (and likely everyone) to write a script to rename the files after exportation.  That way, you don't have to worry about catching all of the cases/ instances within the 3000 lines of code that someone else wrote and just fix it with a simple program at the other end.  Becomes a much more tractable problem that way.

As an aside, I currently use dcm2niix ( available from [GitHub](https://github.com/rordenlab/dcm2niix) or [NITRC](https://www.nitrc.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/dcm2nii:MainPage)) for this conversion outside of MATLAB.

Comment: I will try to rename all files with an additonal nd seperate script like https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1760-how-to-rename-a-bunch-of-files-in-a-folder

Comment: Thank you very much. Until now I was still looking in wrong direction. I will try this solution for rename all files in a directory by using movefile. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893094/change-file-names]